# How to deploy Spring Boot (1.3.6) or any Spring Boot project (connection to cloud database) to Google App Engine?

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I want to deploy spring boot application (connect to cloud sql and return result) on Google App Engine, please share what are the steps to deploy it.

Comment: I want to deploy spring boot application(connect to cloud sql and return                     result) on Google App Engine, please share what are the steps to deploy it.
    i added the dependencies of google appengine in pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You can try jenkins auto deployment feature to deploy the application on to the server

Refer this link to get more Idea on jenkins.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_automated_deployment.htm

please share more info on what is the server and how do you set up connection with database for more info.